# How do I get a Tree given an Ident?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Say I have `lhs`, `tpe`, `rhs` extracted from this:

`q"$mods val $lhs: $tpe = $rhs"`

Now, `tpe` is an `Ident`. How do I get the `Tree` (or `Type`) object corresponding to this ident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ident is a tree representing a name, and the type is assigned by typechecking.

```
scala> import reflect.runtime._,universe._,tools.reflect._
import reflect.runtime._
import universe._
import tools.reflect._

scala> val t = q"val i: Int = 42"
t: reflect.runtime.universe.ValDef = val i: Int = 42

scala> val q"val $x: $what = $rhs" = t
x: reflect.runtime.universe.TermName = i
what: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = Int
rhs: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = 42

scala> showRaw(what)
res1: String = Ident(TypeName("Int"))

scala> val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@27d5a580

scala> val v = tb.typecheck(t)
v: tb.u.Tree = val i: Int = 42

scala> v.children.head.tpe
res2: tb.u.Type = Int
```

Comment: Hm... works fine in `sbt console`, but fails with `sbt run` and in IDE. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: You need the compiler.jar for toolbox.